# I only get second .innerHTML result, first one isn't running

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't get first .innerHTML. It shows 64 but not 125. Why?

```js
    let result=document.querySelector('#reck');
    function getPow(x,y=2) {
        return Math.pow(x,y);
}   
    result.innerHTML= getPow(5,3);
    result.innerHTML= getPow(8);
```

```html
<p id="reck"></p>
```

Thank you by now.

Comment: because you overwriting it

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Do you expect them to append? Or show one after another? You immediately overwrite the `innerHTML` after you assign a value to it.

Comment: Meant show one after another, yeah. I added + before "=" and it solved but the thing I struggled is why can't  I use it twice in that way. still it is. @Ivar

Comment: @Nsur Because `=` assigns a value to something. If you first assign `1` and then assign `2`, the value of `innerHTML` will be `2` because that is the last value you assigned to it. `=` doesn't append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment above, you **overwrite** the first value by adding the second.

Use `append()` to display two values.

```js
let result=document.querySelector('#reck');
  function getPow(x,y=2) {
    return Math.pow(x,y);
}   

result.append(getPow(5,3) + ' ' + getPow(8));
```

```html
<p id="reck"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assign value to innerHTML
element.innerHTML = "Addigned";

// Append values to innerHTML by using one of the three bellow
element.innerHTML += " Added"; 
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + " Added";
element.append(" Added");

// console log to see what innerHTML is now 
console.log(element.innerHTML) 
// Output: "Addigned Added Added Added"
```